# Stuck in a while loop only sometimes

Tags: java, while-loop, boolean

I am having a heck of a time trying to figure out why I can't leave a loop. What I need to do is leave the loop if my Boolean, *forward*, is set to true. (The Boolean has been set to false above the while loop.

When I run the code snippet below I and enter a positive number I can only enter an unlimited amount a numbers. When I enter a negative number I get one prompt telling me that's not allowed and to try again. After than I am stuck in the similar situation above. It doesn't matter what I enter next it will just keep letting input over and over again.

```
{
        while (forward == false)
            if (n2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, the 0 is not a valid entry for the second number, try again!");
                n2 = in.nextInt();
            }   
            else 
            {
                forward = true;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get away with using no extra variables

```
n2 = in.nextInt();
while (input == 0){
    System.out.println("Sorry, 0 is not valid input");
    n2 = in.nextInt();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

as the forward is a boolean, you can use it directly instead of compare

`forward == false`.

If you wanna use this variable (I will not go thru the path of the best way achieve your aim), you can do the follow:

```
while (!forward) {
   if (n2 == 0) {
      System.out.println("Sorry, the 0 is not a valid entry for the second number, try again!");
      n2 = in.nextInt();
   } else {
      forward = true;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have an outer while loop that makes you go back into your while loop? An efficient way to solve loop issues is to debug the code a line at a time.

If you are in Eclipse, set a breakpoint (a place where your program will pause) by clicking on the line number just before entering the while loop. Then run the program, and you will see the current line highlighted. Then move line by line by pressing F6 repeatedly. In the bottom pane you can also find the current values of variables.

Now if you inspect your code line by line you will have a better idea of what's going on.